# What's the maximum amount by which we can spread $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose we have $n$ vectors $v_1, ..., v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ on the unit sphere, so $\|v_i\| = 1$ for all $i$. What's the maximum amount by which we can spread the vectors from each other? i.e. what's  $\arg \max_\theta \min_{i,j} \cos^{-1}(v_i \cdot v_j)$?

Comment: this might have something to do with circle packings on a sphere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing#Packings_on_the_sphere and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01192589 and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mirko indicated, your question is equivalent to asking for optimal [sphere packings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing)
in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

There has been a recent advance for $n \in \{8,24\}$:

> Erica Klarreich. "Sphere Packing Solved in Higher Dimensions."
>   *Quanta*. 30Mar2016. 
>   [Journal link](https://www.quantamagazine.org/sphere-packing-solved-in-higher-dimensions-20160330/).
>
> "In a pair of papers posted online this month, a Ukrainian mathematician [[Maryna Viazovska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maryna_Viazovska)] has solved two high-dimensional versions of the centuries-old “sphere packing” problem. In dimensions $8$ and $24$ (the latter dimension in collaboration with other researchers), she has proved that two highly symmetrical arrangements pack spheres together in the densest possible way."

See also the MO question: [Distributing points evenly on a sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/a/212556/6094).